# mod_headers RequestHeaders ignores env argument for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I want to disable Cookies for a Wordpress-Site on the www-subdomain and only want the cookies to work on "admin.mydomain.com". (Reasoning behind this is to avoid getting Admin-UI cached within the CloudFlare Proxy).

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^www.mydomain.com$" REMOVE_COOKIES
Header unset Cookie env=REMOVE_COOKIES
Header unset Set-Cookie env=REMOVE_COOKIES
RequestHeader unset Cookie env=REMOVE_COOKIES

# ...

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

- `admin.mydomain.com/test.php` gets the cookies.
- `admin.mydomain.com/some-blog-post` doesn't get the cookies (and thus features like Preview are broken)

Are mod_rewrite and mod_headers incompatible?